# Org mode clock-in report by time

Tags: org-mode

I'm looking for a script for an orgmode report that reports on what I've done as a kind of "diary format" instead of by task as is usual by default.

A summary of what I've done would also be good. I rarely clock out before the end of the day so the clock out time of the previous task is the clock in time of the next task (this happens automatically when I clock something in). This is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
|       Date | Time Start | Time End | Task                             | Current Task Status |
|------------+------------+----------+----------------------------------+---------------------|
| 2018-01-01 |      09:03 |    10:27 | Meeting                          | No Status           |
| 2018-01-01 |      10:27 |    11:34 | Write SQL for London Data Return | Done                |
| 2018-01-01 |      11:34 |    12:02 | Admin                            | No Status           |
| 2018-01-01 |      12:02 |    12:30 | Lunch                            | No Status           |
| 2018-01-01 |      12:30 |    14:55 | Complete Performance Report      | Todo                |
| 2018-01-01 |      14:55 |    15:03 | ~No Task has been Clocked~       |                     |
| 2018-01-01 |      15:03 |    17:08 | Complete Performance Report      | Done                |

Summary of 2018-01-01
Hours worked: 07:37
Time Ahead: +00:07
Time not Clocked: 00:08
```

Do you know if something similar exists? This is basically something I'm looking at to "justify" my time to those higher powers that assume we spend the day browsing Reddit and secretly vaping at our desks.